# How to find something in a string with PHP

Tags: php

I'm a little green with PHP, as i have coded in ASP classic before and it's really not the same

I have 3 strings containing the following text:

```
$str1 = "is simply dummy text of the printing $$ 6/4r $$ and typesetting industry"
$str2 = "is simply dummy text of the printing $$ 11/11tr $$ and typesetting industry"
$str3 = "is simply dummy text of the printing $$ 15/6 $$ and typesetting industry"
```

How can i get `6/4r`, `11/11tr` and `15/6` out in seperate variables?

1. I think it something like search for `$$`
2. Ask, is the next char a space?
3. Ask, is the next char a number?
4. Ask, is the next char a '/'

When all these are true i want to grab `6/4r` and put it in a separate var.

How can I do this in PHP?

Comment: Have you done any web searches on searching strings in php yet?

Comment: You should research regex. It's wonderful really.

Comment: read what regular expressions are for

Comment: @Fluffeh In this case, it can be done by simple splitting the string, which should always be preferred.

Comment: Not going to make an answer out of it, since this should be closed. Read the manual on [preg_match](http://php.net/preg_match)

Comment: Thanks for all the inputs guys.

Answer (score 6):

How about `explode`:

```
var_dump(explode('$$', $str1));

array(3) {
 [0] => string(37) "is simply dummy text of the printing "
 [1] => string(6) " 6/4r " 
 [2]=>  string(25) " and typesetting industry"
}
```

So `trim($array[1])` will always return the segment you want.

Comment: I would always prefer regex over a method like this.

Comment: I would always prefer native functions over regex.

Comment: Thank you for the example Martin, will try to see if this works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Regex:

```
$str = 'is simply dummy text of the printing $$ 6/4r $$ and typesetting industr';

preg_match('|\$\$(.*)\$\$|',$str,$match);

echo $match[1];
```

Comment: Thank you navnav, i will try this as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the best way but i'll use explode function

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

```
$pieces = explode(' \$\$ ', $str1);
//Should contain 6/4r
echo $pieces[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

use `preg_match` to find every thing (that is not a space) between the dollar signs

```
function getValue($str){
    $pattern = '/\$\$\s*([^\$\s]+)\s*\$\$/i';
    if(preg_match($pattern, $str, $match)){
        return $match[1];
    }
    return false;
}

echo getValue($str1);
```

Comment: Thanks Yaron, i will try this as well.